# MapInfo "Error during Read: XML Library Load Error Required XML version unavailable"

Tags: mapinfo, asp.net, xml

I am using MapExtreme 7.0, I am running into the following error on an asp.net website (.net 3.5) running on a server with windows 2003 32bit.

"Error during Read: XML Library Load Error Required XML version unavailable" when trying to access some feature data.

I managed to track down some obscure reference in the 6.7.1 release notes and the fix was to install the latest "XML", I'm assuming that refers to MSXML, I have checked and the server has MSXML 6 installed.

Is there something else this may be referring to? Or is there another cause of the problem.

I managed to reflect the MapInfo dlls and have found the resource that contains the string but I cannot find where the error actually originates from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that [MSXML 4.0 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19662) is required to be installed even if you have a later version of it already installed